# Reactstrap modal showing extra div with zindex value outside modal

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, reactstrap

I am using [Reactstrap Modal](https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-modal--modal) to show modal in my page, but it is showing an additional div wrapping over rendered modal div.

```
<div tabindex="-1" style="position: relative; z-index: 1050; display: block;">
  <div class="">
    <div class="modal fade show" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The additional `z-index: 1050;` causes problem to show `<header>` over modal in some cases,

I just want to know is there any option to prevent these 2 additional div at the rendering time?

Note: In my code, no outer div  using over `<Modal>` but the problem is **Reactstrap site** also showing these extra divs!

Comment: Those are placeholders. The top-level one places the modal's context over top of the rest, and the "modal fade show" one shows/hides the modal and its backdrop. If your header is showing, it's because its `z-index` is too high. Try lowering it.